# Is there a way to plus one to an Enum Bounded Ord type in a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have the following data type:

```
data Suit = Club | Diamond | Heart | Spade
      deriving (Eq, Ord, Bounded, Enum)

data Rank =
R2 | R3 | R4 | R5 | R6 | R7 | R8 | R9 | R10 |
Jack | Queen | King | Ace
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Bounded, Enum)

data Card = Card {suit::Suit, rank::Rank}
      deriving (Eq, Bounded)
```

and now have a list of `[Card]`. Is there a way that I can make a `Rank` of certain `Card` in the list plus one? For example given a list `[Card Club R2, Card Club R2]` I want to make it `[Card Club R3, Card Club R3]`. I've written the following code:

```
-- | Update certain number of cards' rank in the list.
updateRankList :: Int -> [Card] -> [Card]

updateRankList num (x : xs)
    | num == 0  = []
    | otherwise = updateRank x ++ updateRankList (num - 1) xs

-- | Update a card's rank, didn't finish.
updateRank :: Card -> Card

updateRank card =
```

And I'm stuck. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: as always, please think about boundary conditions, and update your question.

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure what you mean by boundary conditions.

Comment: What is the 'plus one' rank of `Ace`? Should it wrap around to `R2`?

Comment: So going from `R2` to `R3`, since it's an `Enum` should be pretty simple.  What functions are defined for the `Enum` typeclass?  (hint: try `:info Enum` in GHCi)

Comment: Thanks! The data type is provide by my professor and I'm new to these type classes. I'll definitely check it!

Comment: I think the only reason to wrap are certain straight starting at Ace - I did something similar (poker hand kata) here: https://gist.github.com/CarstenKoenig/3ad8bf24ceb4d556c5bf - maybe you'll find something helpful there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a wrapping succ for Bounded and Enum types:

```
 succWrap x = if x == maxBound then minBound else succ x
```

then you need just

```
 updateRanks n xs = map succWrap (take num xs) ++ drop num xs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:info Enum
```

is pretty useful! The function I'm looking for is `succ`, thanks guys.